# When converting mkv to mp4, the audio is lost

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, mp4, video-encoding, mkv

I have converted my .mkv file into an .mp4 by using the command:

```
sudo avconv -i input.mkv -codec copy output.mp4
```

I am trying to play the mp4 file in the browser, but the audio is not playing. The video player shows that it is on mute, but the button is disabled so you cannot turn it off of mute.

Other mp4s are working, but they were not converted from .mkv. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: this is a software question/issue. Should it be moved to a different forum?

Comment: 1. Why `sudo`? 2. Maybe try ffmpeg instead.

Comment: @jangler you mean why avconv. but again this is not a software recommendation forum

Comment: @Braim no, I'm wondering why a substitute user is needed to convert a video file.

Comment: @EvanCarslake or software recommendation?

Comment: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ is the place to ask this question.

Comment: From what I've read in http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, it qualifies to be in here. There is a bit of source code, and is related to a software tool (maybe not commonly used). And why the recommendation instead of trying to help him solve the problem with using `avconv` ?

Comment: What kind of audio? Check it out with `mediainfo` or `ffprobe`.

Comment: I'm sorry to post in the incorrect place. Thank you for adding the link about what is on topic!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In an MP4 container, [browsers usually support only H.264 video and either AAC or MP3 audio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats#MP4_H.264_%28AAC_or_MP3%29).  The output from your `avconv` command should show the format of your video and audio; look under "Input #0" for the lines that start with "Stream #".  If you audio is not already AAC or MP3 you will want to convert it instead of just copying it to the MP4 container.  You can copy the video and convert only the audio with a command like this:

```
avconv -i input.mkv -c:v copy -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 2 output.mp4
```

The `-c:v copy` will copy the video, and `-c:a libmp3lame` will convert the audio to MP3 using the `libmp3lame` encoder.  `-q:a 2` sets the audio quality; use a lower number for better quality (and a larger file).  You could instead [convert to AAC audio](https://wiki.libav.org/Encoding/aac) if your `avconv` was configured with non-free codecs enabled and a good quality AAC encoder.

Comment: MP4 also supports AC3 and, if you mux with LSmash, DTS.

Comment: It does, but most browsers do not support that.

Comment: Thank you! It was the wrong kind of audio. I didn't know that about browsers!

Comment: I tried the above command but giving error `Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:1 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
`